# Addition of custom emoticons on Soft Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I am very new to app development, I have developed a softkeyboard from an existing source, I have referred to the `SDK softkeyboard sample` but there isnt any help there on adding emoticons.

I want to add my own emoticons to the softkeyboard, how do I go about accomplishing this? From what I have researched I've only found how to create the actual soft keyboard itself but I have found nothing on how to create a custom one (with addition of your own emoticons). any advice, blogposts or references pertaining to how to add custom emoticons to a softkeyboard will be greatly appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: Its not really a problem I was looking for advice on how to actually add my own emoticons such as an example code or blog.. of how to add them to my softkeyboard....

Comment: oh yes I believe Morpheus did..I accepted it Im new to the site and app development Im just trying to find help Im confused and sometimes confusion makes it hard to ask the right questions the right way...

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 1):

Add a keyboard layout in XML, similar to `qwerty.xml`, `symbols.xml`, etc., replacing the keys with keys that use your emoticon icons (`android:keyIcon="@drawable/smiley_icon"`, for example) and that output that text for the emoticon (`android:keyOutputText=":-)"`, for example).  Then add a keyboard, named something like mEmoticonKeyboard, to your SoftKeyboard class and instantiate it in the same way that `mQwertyKeyboad`, `mSymbolsKeyboard`, etc. are created.

To show this keyboard, add it to the keyboard rotation cycle on `handleShift()`.